# Matching a string with dynamic numbers for Regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I got a query string in my URL string such as this

www.mylink.com?query1=2&query2=15

Query1 might contain any numbers and become this

www.mylink.com?query1=256&query2=15

So , my code will dynamically calculate a new value for query1 , and I wanted to replace the value into the URL string . So far I've tried

```
var re = new RegExp("query1=" + "[0-9999]" , "g");
```

but it only replaces the first digit . How do I achieve it to replace any numbers after the "=" sign ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result = subject.replace(/(query1=)(\d+)/ig, "$1222");
```

where the replacement number is 222
or:

```
var myregexp = /(query1=)(\d+)/i;
result = subject.replace(myregexp, "$1222");
```